# My link is no responsive after or not generated after using get_url_absolute

Tags: django, django-models

The two links are not working despite of the using get_absolute_ur to get the object url in my models.
How do i configure the code to make my links responsive
 [PICTUREOF THE SITE IMAGE AND LINKS THAT ARE NOT WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYJhL.jpg)
MY VIEWS:BELOW
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
    from .models import Category, Product
    # from django.template import RequestContext

```
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    page_title = 'Musical Instruments and Sheet Music for Musicians'
    return render(request, 'catalog/index.html')


def show_category(request, category_slug=None):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
    page_title = c.name
    meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
    meta_description = c.meta_description
    return render(request, 'catalog/category.html', {'c': c})


def show_product(request, product_slug=None):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
    categories = p.categories.filter(is_active=True)
    page_title = p.name
    meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords
    meta_description = p.meta_description
    return render(request, 'catalog/product.html', {'p': p})
```

MY MODELS:BELOW

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL,created from name.')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255,
                                     help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,
                                        help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Meta:
    db_table = 'categories'
    ordering = ['name']
    verbose_name = 'Category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


def get_absolute_url(self):
    reverse('catalog:catalog_category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
# return 'catalog_category', (), {'category_slug': self.slug}


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL,created from name.')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords", max_length=255,
                                     help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,
                                        help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


class Meta:
    db_table = 'products'
    ordering = ['-created_at']


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


def get_absolute_url(self):
    reverse('catalog:catalog_product', kwargs={"product_slug": self.slug})
#    return 'product_category', (), {'product_slug': self.slug}


def sale_price(self):
    if self.old_price > self.price:
       return self.price
    else:
        return None
```

MY URLS:
    from django.urls import path

```
from . import views

app_name = 'catalog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='catalog_home'),
    path('category/<category_slug>/', views.show_category, name='catalog_category'),
    path('product/<product_slug>', views.show_product, name='catalog_product'),


]

MY TEMPLATE:

   {% extends "catalog.html" %}
   {% block content %}
   <h1>{{ c.name }}</h1>
   {{ c.description }}
   <br /><br />
   {% for p in products %}
   <div class="product_thumbnail">
   <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">
   <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/thumbnails/{{ p.image}}" alt="{{ p.name }}" 
   class="bn" />
   <br />
   {{ p.name }}
   </a>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Inspect your links in browser and check their hrefs. Are they a valid urls in regards to your urls.py? At the same time your get_absolute_url should return reverse not just reverse.

Comment: In your model Category and Product does not have a category_slug and product_slug. It is simply slug. Use `slug = slug`